# Makeindex cannot generate index entries

Tags: makeindex

I have a simple Latex cod

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
\thechapter.\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

Stuff about eigenvectors\index{eigenvector} and eigenvalues\index{eigenvalue}.

\chapter{Another Sample}

Some more stuff about eigenvectors\index{eigenvector} and
eigenvalues\index{eigenvalue}. Something about eigen decomposition\index{eigen-decomposition}.


\printindex

\end{document}
```

There is a problem that Makeindex cannot generate index entries. The main problem is that I want to define a page number with period (dot) between the chapter number and the page number.

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter.\arabic{page}}
```

In this case Makeindex cannot generate index entries. I get a message:

---

Scanning input file in1.idx...done 
(0 entries accepted, 5 rejected).

### Nothing written in in1.ind.

Transcript written in in1.ilg.

However, if I put drag (-) instead period(dot),

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
```

Makeindex generate index entries
What is the problem and why can not I place a point (dot) between the chapter number and the page number?
If someone knows the solution, please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`makeindex`'s default compositor is a hyphen `-`. You can change it in a style file using `page_compositor`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.ist}
page_compositor "."
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
\thechapter.\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

Stuff about eigenvectors\index{eigenvector} and
eigenvalues\index{eigenvalue}.

\chapter{Another Sample}

Some more stuff about eigenvectors\index{eigenvector} and
eigenvalues\index{eigenvalue}. Something about eigen
decomposition\index{eigen-decomposition}.


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Remember to include `-s` *stylefile* when invoking `makeindex`. For example, if the above document is called `myDoc.tex` then

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeindex -s myDoc.ist myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Answer (score 3):

MakeIndex doesn't accept “composite” page numbers. A crude but effective workaround, if you have no special needs for the index entries, can be using a different representation of the page numbers (chapter by 1000 plus page).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter.\arabic{page}}
\newcommand\thecomplexpage{\the\numexpr\value{chapter}*1000+\value{page}\relax}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@wrindex}[1]{%
  \protected@write\@indexfile{\let\thecomplexpage\relax}{%
    \string\indexentry{#1|decomposepage}{\thecomplexpage}%
  }%
  \endgroup\@esphack
}
\newcommand\decomposepage[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@tempcnta=#1\relax
  \divide\@tempcnta by 1000
  \the\@tempcnta.\the\numexpr#1-1000*\@tempcnta\relax
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

Stuff about eigenvectors\index{eigenvector} and eigenvalues\index{eigenvalue}.

\chapter{Another Sample}

Some more stuff about eigenvectors\index{eigenvector} and
eigenvalues\index{eigenvalue}. Something about eigen decomposition\index{eigen-decomposition}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]